# How To Display the Array Response by without braces and commas in UI using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, web

I am getting the Array Response ["item1","item2"] from the server. but i want to display the data as item1 and item2 in one by one in UI using angularjs. So, Please give me the solution?

Comment: Sorry there is no magical solution Start by reading the angular docs.

Comment: First You need to improve the post with what have you tried to stop down votings and to get some answers. I down voted you because of reason of asking directly for solution with out trying Let me Know when you update the Post i can lift my down vote Refer :- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i am getting the response from the server like "items": [ "Veg, Rotis,Dalu"] so, i want to value of the items as normal data (removing [,],",") so, please help for the code in angularjs

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-repeat`

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  your response is wrong for your requirement I guess. I should be `{"items":["veg", "rotis", "Dalu"]}`, then you can assign to a scope like `$scope.items = yourResponse.items;` in controller and in html you can ng-repeat it like, 
`<span ng-repeat="item in items" ng-bind="item"></span>`

---

and if you can't change your response, if it had to come like you mentioned, then you can do it in following way.
in controller,

```
var items = yourResponse.items[0];
$scope.items = items.split(',');
```

html same as above,
`<span ng-repeat="item in items" ng-bind="item"></span>`